# RStudio - Error on saving files in non-home directory

Tags: r, rstudio-server

I am trying to save R Scripts in non-home directories, eg: `/mnt/MOUNT_POINT_A` but on saving, it throws out error `Error Saving file: No such file or directory`.

While I save anything in home directory of user logged in, its successful.
I was facing similar issues while reading non-home directory located files, so I had to whitelist the directories I was trying to read from?

Is there any such configuration for saving a file as well?

Note: I am running RStudio server as root but all logged users' processes will start with their user ids only.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if there is an existence file as you call directory it should be ok but try with `/ // \ \\` may help

```
/mnt/MOUNT_POINT_A this is at the same location with your R?
```

Comment: Try to take the full name of the directory, so it should be something like "C:/Users/Avik/mnt/MOUNT_POINT_A"

Comment: Please note I am running RStudio server on Centos .

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using backslash instead of slash, and double backslash since only one will make the r escape the characters.

Ex:

```r
\\mnt\\MOUNT_POINT_A\\file.ext
```

Comment: This is saving the file in my home directory with the exact name `\\mnt\\MOUNT_POINT_A\\file.ext`. Please note, I have set my current working directory has the mount point itself to directory read and save files there only.

Comment: even if you use ```//mnt//MOUNT_POINT_A//```?

Comment: @Pedo: with `//` i get the same error as shown in questions. `Error saving file: No such file or directory`